# SVG generated with D3 doesn't scale like seemingly identical static SVG content

Tags: d3.js, responsive-design

I'm generating an svg visualization with d3 that I'd like to have scale with it's container in a responsive way. I can directly create an SVG element that behaves this way, but when I write a d3 script that generates the same SVG markup, it doesn't scale.

Here's the d3 code that generates the SVG element:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(36)
    .outerRadius(48);

var svg = d3.select('#d3').append('svg')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '100%')
            .attr('viewbox', '0, 0, 100, 100')
            .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid')
            .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 50)');

var loop = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'percent-wheel');

loop.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'background')
    .attr('d', arc.endAngle(2 * Math.PI));
```

And here's the resulting SVG markup, which scales correctly when inserted into the DOM statically:

```
<div id="d3" class="container">   
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewbox="0, 0, 100, 100" height="100%" width="100%">
    <g transform="translate(50, 50)">
      <g class="percent-wheel">
        <path d="M0,48A48,48 0 1,1 0,-48A48,48 0 1,1 0,48M0,36A36,36 0 1,0 0,-36A36,36 0 1,0 0,36Z" class="background"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can see a live example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMQGq/

Can anyone explain what's different about creating the svg via d3 that causes this to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Neither of the circles scales when I resize the window.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. One circle has scaled to the size of its containing element (the .container div), the other hasn't.

Comment: There's a typo in your attribute definition -- it should be `viewBox` instead of `viewbox`.

Comment: That's interesting - and solves my problem - Thanks!. Out of curiosity: any idea why the typo causes problems in d3, but not in the static markup?

Comment: My guess is that the browser "normalizes" the attribute names when parsing the page and that this doesn't happen for content that is generated dynamically, but I'm really just guessing here.

Comment: It's interesting that this occurs in Chrome, IE & Firefox (i.e. all the ones I quickly checked).

Comment: Yes, the fact that it was consistent across browsers really threw me, and made me think it was something that was happening by design, as opposed to the sometimes-occurring typo auto-correction it seems to be

Comment: Please mark this is answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a typo in the attribute definition -- it should be `viewBox` instead of `viewbox`.